# Deleting certain elements of a list

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, string-manipulation

This query is similar to a [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/155913) I posted earlier.

Given

```
testList = 
  {{"a", "b 3", "cd", "ef 23"}, {"z 12", "y", "x"}, {"z", "y"}, {"a", "b3"}};
```

I would like to create a rule that would delete 1st level elements of `testList` that do not contain a string representation of a number.  The result would be:

```
resultList = {{"a", "b 3", "cd", "ef 23"}, {"z 12", "y", "x"}, {"a", "b3"}};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although I very much in favor of aardvark2012's answer using `Pick`, I would like to note that this can done with good old `Table`.

```
data = {{"a", "b 3", "cd", "ef 23"}, {"z 12", "y", "x"}, {"z", "y"}, {"a", "b3"}};
Table[If[Or @@ StringContainsQ[item, DigitCharacter], item, Nothing], {item, data}]
```

> `{{"a", "b 3", "cd", "ef 23"}, {"z 12", "y", "x"}, {"a", "b3"}}`

Answer (score 8):

One possibility:

```
Pick[#, Or @@@ StringContainsQ[DigitCharacter] /@ #] &@testList2
```

or

```
Select[testList2, Or @@ StringContainsQ[#, DigitCharacter] &]
```

Answer (score 2):

If the OP really wants a [`Rule`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule.html) then anothe options is:

```
rule = Rule[
  PatternTest[Blank[List],
   Composition[
    Not,
    Apply[Or],
    Map[StringContainsQ[DigitCharacter]]
    ]
   ]
  , Nothing
  ]
```

Or

```
rule= _List?(Not@*Apply[Or]@*Map[StringContainsQ[DigitCharacter]]) -> Nothing
```

Then

```
testList /. rule
(* {{"a", "b 3", "cd", "ef 23"}, {"z 12", "y", "x"}, {"a", "b3"}} *)

(testList /. rule) == resultList
(* True *)
```

Comment: Although admonished not to say thanks, I'll say thanks /@ aardvark2012, m_goldberg,rhermans :)